# Why is voting disabled in the Triage queue?

Tags: discussion, triage

As it stands now, voting is currently disabled in the "Triage" queue, but not in the "First Post" queue.

What is the rationale behind this? Why am I not supposed to downvote/upvote good or bad questions?

Comment: Because we want reviewers to focus on the main goal of that queue.